# command-line line 0: unsupported option "accept-new", how to fix this?

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services

Earlier it used to work for checking ssh login passes or not.

```
args="-oStrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new "
test_command="ssh -i ssh_key.pem ec2-user@ec2-34-211-110-254.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com $args"
until eval "$test_command'echo' >/dev/null" 2>log; do
  handle_ssh_errors "$(cat log)"
  echo "Waiting for login permissions to propagate..."
  sleep 10
done
```

But when I checked now, able to login the machine with below command.

[ssh login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SO4En.png)

But running the eval command giving me an error.

```
[vagrant@localhost aws]$ eval "$test_command'echo' >/dev/null" 2>log
[vagrant@localhost aws]$ cat log
command-line line 0: unsupported option "accept-new".
```

Please suggest how to fix this

Answer (score 3):

Try to upgrade your ssh.
`OpenSSH releases prior to OpenSSH 7.6 (released Oct 2017) do not support the ssh command line argument used to accept first connection. Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7, CentOS 7, AWS Linux 2, and Debian 9 all deliver OpenSSH releases older than OpenSSH 7.6.`

Here is the reference url: https://plugins.jenkins.io/git-client/

Comment: I followed the steps in this gist to resolve the issue of upgrading OpenSSH: https://gist.github.com/roommen/18cd78d07b0fbc962de4e79c1d468f92